# How to fix error while trying to pass multiple models to one view in Asp.Net Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to pass some models to one view. What I've done so far is something like this:

OrderTypeModel:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class OrderTypeModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string OrderType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OrderStatusModel:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class OrderStatusModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OrderSizeModel:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class OrderSizeModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string OrderSize { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OrderModel:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class OrdersModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public int OrderType_Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderStatus_Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderSize_Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

And there's a `MultipleViewsModel`:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class MultipleViewsModel
    {
        public List<OrderTypeModel> Type { get; set; }
        public List<OrderSizeModel> Size { get; set; }
        public List<OrderStatusModel> Status { get; set; }
        public OrdersModel Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`OrderType_Id`, `OrderStatus_Id`, and `OrderSize_Id` are Foreign Keys in my database. Now When I need to call them all in a form, it throws an error:

My View is something like this:

```
@model MultipleViewsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Orders.Title" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Orders.Title" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Orders.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Orders.OrderType_Id" class="control-label"></label>
    @{
        foreach (var ot in ViewData["OrderType"] as Type)
        {
            <input asp-for="Orders.OrderType_Id" type="radio" value=@ot.Id name=@ot.OrderType. class="form-control" />
        }
    }
    <span asp-validation-for="Orders.OrderType_Id" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And my Controller is something like this:

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["OrderType"] = _context.OrderType
                .Any();
            ViewData["OrderSize"] = _context.OrderSize.Any();
            return View();
        }
```

I need to put the models in radio forms. But an error is thrown at this line in view:

```
foreach (var ot in ViewData["OrderType"] as Type)
```

And says `Type is not found in current context`.

Note that I've cut a major part of what was not needed and so my form in the view is not complete just to be succinct.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: If your `ViewData["OrderType"]` is a `List` of Type `OrderTypeModel`, then you can simply loop over it  using: `foreach (var ot in ViewData["OrderType"] as List<OrderTypeModel>)`

Comment: That's not asp.net-core. It's sound like Asp.Net Forms

Comment: @Reza Kazemifar why you use ViewData if you have model with list type?

Comment: You’re doing it incorrectly. `Model` (note capital M) is your model, not `ViewData` and you pass it to your view like this: `return View(model);`, where the type of `model` matches your declared model in your view; i.e. `MultipleViewsModel` here.

Comment: @RahulSharma It throws an exception saying: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` :-(

Comment: @evilGenius I'm new to Asp, and I have no idea of many things... :-)

Comment: Thank you dear @sellotape! but when I `return View(MutipleViewsModel)` it says `MultipleViewsModel is a type which is not valid in the given context`. Sorry I'm an absolute newbie!

Comment: @RezaKazemifar if you need i can help you replace viewData on model and use it

Comment: @evilGenius Thank you very much dearest evil. Got my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use view model as you have included in your page :

```
@model MultipleViewsModel
```

On server side , you should initialize the model class and set the values . For example , you can fill the `Type` in `create` action like :

```
MultipleViewsModel multipleViewsModel = new MultipleViewsModel();
multipleViewsModel.Type = new List<OrderTypeModel>();
multipleViewsModel.Type = db.orderTypes.ToList();

multipleViewsModel.Orders = new OrdersModel() { OrderType_Id = 2 };

return View(multipleViewsModel);
```

On client side , you can loop the `OrderTypeModel` list and set default value by which matches the `OrderType_Id` :

```
@{
  foreach (var orderType in Model.Type)
  {
      <input asp-for="Orders.OrderType_Id" type="radio" value=@orderType.Id name=Orders.OrderType_Id />
      @Html.Label("OrderType" + orderType.Id, orderType.OrderType)
  }
}
```

Comment: You made my day! THANK YOU very much! :-)